How to Mount a Bootable Debian SD Card on macOS and Windows?
I'm having trouble mounting a bootable Debian OS on SD Card (32GB) on macOS and Windows. The drive mounts and functions perfectly on my Linux machine, allowing read/write access. However, neither macOS nor Windows will mount the drive. Does anyone know if it's possible to mount and access a bootable Debian external hard drive on macOS and Windows, and if so, how to achieve this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

It’s very simple: Neither macOS nor Windows support Linux filesystems. What’s your goal in this?

What file system did you use for the partition? I assume you used a Linux specific file system (such as ext4), which, as @DanielB states isn't (natively) supported by Windows/MacOS. If you're aiming to create a device that can be read by all 3 operating systems, you'll want to use a different system; perhaps ExFat or NTFS.

I want to do debian os customization ( update the host name, user name/password and etc...).

This is starting to smell like an XY Problem.

like rasperry pi imager

If you want to customize a Linux distribution for your Raspberry Pi, modifying it directly may not be your only choice.
Debian for Raspberry Pi can be pre-configured using sysconf.txt. This is also what Raspberry Pi Imager uses. This file would reside on the boot partition which is accessible to all operating systems. You can learn about this mechanism here and here. It is rather basic. However, it’s enough for setting the hostname and local/SSH credentials:
hostname=mypi1234
root_pw=s00p3rs3cr3t
root_authorized_key=ssh-rsa AAAA3NbzayC1Ec2AAAAd…

Apparently, dropping a wpa_supplicant.conf into the boot partition will no longer give you Wi-Fi access, because nowadays it’s Network Manager.
To find out what exactly it is Raspberry Pi Imager does, check its source code or refer to this article (could become outdated soon).
A different example: Ubuntu comes with cloud-init allowing for virtually any customization you could imagine. You would simply create a text file called “user-data” on the boot partition. cloud-init is very powerful, but can sometimes be complicated.

As written in my comment, neither macOS nor Windows support Linux filesystems. If you do want to access the root partition, you should do so from Linux. Depending on your SD card reader, a virtual machine would be sufficient.

I wouldn't do this on a Windows or Mac. If that's all you have, you can set up a VM on your windows or mac with VMware workstation, create a linux VM, run it, then mount it to the VM. Do this or find another linux system to which you can connect and access this drive. I'm not sure what other options you have.
